# How to use a custom elastic net function with glmnet in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, caret, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am doing binary classification with Elastic Net Logistic Regression in R.
Now I want to customize the elastic net function to contain "Correlation Based Elastic Net Penalties". see the formula below.
Is there a way to specify custom penalties like this in R using the *glmnet* or *Caret* package?
Thanks in advance!

[Regular Elastic Net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frqG6.png)'
[Custom Elastic Net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaQzl.png)

Comment: I don't think you can do this with `glmnet`. There are packages that can help with this however, such as `lars` package helps `glmnet` with fitting these things. I'd ask over at stats.stackoverflow.com

Comment: See [CRAN Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html) and especially the section called "Regularized and Shrinkage Methods" for suggestions.